# Tensorflow: Masking an array based on duplicated elements of another array

Tags: python, tensorflow, unique, mask

I have an array, `x=[2, 3, 4, 3, 2]` which contains the states of model and another  array which gives corresponding probabilities of these states, `prob=[.2, .1, .4, .1, .2]`. But some states are duplicated and I need to sum their corresponding probabilities. So my desired outputs are: `unique_elems=[2, 3, 4]` and `reduced_prob=[.2+.2, .1+.1, .4]`. Here is my approach:

```py
x = tf.constant([2, 3, 4, 3, 2])
prob = tf.constant([.2, .1, .4, .1, .2])
unique_elems, _ = tf.unique(x)  # [2, 3, 4]
unique_elems = tf.expand_dims(unique_elems, axis=1) # [[2], [3], [4]]

tiled_prob = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(prob, axis=0), [3, 1]) 
# [[0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2],
#  [0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2],
#  [0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2]]

equal = tf.equal(x, unique_elems)
# [[ True, False, False, False,  True],
#  [False,  True, False,  True, False],
#  [False, False,  True, False, False]]

reduced_prob = tf.multiply(tiled_prob, tf.cast(equal, tf.float32))
# [[0.2, 0. , 0. , 0. , 0.2],
#  [0. , 0.1, 0. , 0.1, 0. ],
#  [0. , 0. , 0.4, 0. , 0. ]]

reduced_prob = tf.reduce_sum(reduced_prob, axis=1)
# [0.4, 0.2, 0.4]
```

but I am wondering whether there is a more efficient way to do that. In particular I am using tile operation which I think is not very efficient for large arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done in two lines by [`tf.unsorted_segment_sum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/unsorted_segment_sum):

```
unique_elems, idx = tf.unique(x)  # [2, 3, 4]
reduced_prob = tf.unsorted_segment_sum(prob, idx, tf.size(unique_elems))
```